# jQuery & Objects, trying to make a lightweight widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make a make generic select "control" that I can dynamically add elements to, but I am having trouble getting functions to work right.

This is what I started with.

```
$select = $("<select></select>");
$select.addOption = function(value,text){
  $(this).append($("<option></option>").val(value).text(text));
};
```

This worked fine alone but anytime `$select` is `.clone(true)`'ed the `addOption()` function is lost.

This is my object approach but still the function does not work.

```
function $selectX() {
  return $("<select></select>");
}

$selectX.prototype.addOption() = function(value,text){
  $(this).append($("<option></option>").val(value).text(text));
};
```

Hack solution is to add the function manually after creation:

```
$nameSelect= new $selectX;
$nameSelect.addOption = function(value,text){
  $(this).append($("<option></option>").val(value).text(text));
};
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add new method to jQuery You need to use `jQuery.fn.methodName` attribute, so in this case it will be:

```
jQuery.fn.addOption = function (value, text) {
    jQuery(this).append(jQuery('<option></option>').val(value).text(text));
};
```

But keep in mind that this `addOption` will be accessible from result of any `$()` call.